# How to dynamically obtain the Function Name that executed another Function?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, arguments

I need to find a dynamic way to know which function (which are more than 2) executed another certain function, in which will return the caller function.

I currently have the following code, which doesn't work:

```
function Hello() {
  _alert("caller is " + Hello().caller);
}

Bye();
function Bye() {
  Hello();
}
```

The error message is the following: ***ReferenceError: Hello is not defined***

If this method doesn't work, maybe it is possible through Parameters?

There can be multiple Executer Funtions upon the Target Function that delivers the Executer Function Name which time it is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Hello` without calling it:

```js
function Hello() {
  alert("caller is " + Hello.caller);
}

Bye();
function Bye() {
  Hello();
}
```

But keep in mind that this code will work only in non-strict mode. Such code will throw an error:

```js
'use strict';
function Hello() {
  alert("caller is " + Hello.caller);
}

Bye();
function Bye() {
  Hello();
}
```

Comment: This is deprecated and will not work in strict mode, and not in all browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/caller

Answer (score 1):

There once were `arguments.callee` and `arguments.caller` (you can google them), but now they are deprecated, and there is no way to know the caller nowadays. You should do something like this:

```
function Hello(caller) {
  alert("caller is " + caller);
}

Bye();
function Bye() {
  Hello('Bye');
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work... and I need to return the Executer Function Name dynamically (because there can be more than 1, all with different names). Lastly, it returns the following alert: "caller is " + caller

Comment: Nope. Re-checked it, it works. F12, ctrl+v, Enter. Gives the expected alert "Caller is Bye". Are you on Chrome?  *more than 1, all with different names* - so every such function should send its name. There is no other way. Only maybe some flavors of this approach.